# Why can't Java find a CSV file saved in the same folder as the class? Using duke.edu FileResource

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to get Java to open a CSV File (which is saved in the same folder as the Java project) and parse its contents. I have included in my code the file path but when I run the program it says it cannot access the file.  The FileResource object is from dukelearntoprogram.com

I have tried different versions of the file path which include more steps in the path. I have tried running the program with this parameter blank, in which case FileResource opens a file navigation window. When the specified file is manually selected in this window everything goes as expected but I can't get it to open automatically from a String of the file path.

```
public void testHottestInDay () {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource("ParsingCSVdata/weather_data/2015/weather-2015-01-01.csv");  
        CSVRecord largest = hottestHourInFile(fr.getCSVParser());
        System.out.println("Hottest temperature was " + largest.get("TemperatureF") + " at " + largest.get("TimeEST"));
```

When I try running the program with the file path specified as above I get this error message:
    edu.duke.ResourceException: FileResource: cannot access 
    ParsingCSVdata/weather_data/2015/weather-2015-01-01
    at edu.duke.FileResource.initRead(FileResource.java:370)
    at edu.duke.FileResource.(FileResource.java:95)
    at CSVMax.testHottestInDay(CSVMax.java:31).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out by trial and error that the solution was to specify LESS of the file path. Because the java project was in the same file as the data, namely "ParsingCSVdata", this step needed to be left out of the file path. 
When I ran the program with the second line from above replaced by: 
    FileResource fr = new FileResource("weather_data/2015/weather-2015-01-01.csv");
I got the expected result.
I am still surprised by what I've learned though, Why should it be a problem to give Too much background information about where a file resides?

Comment: That's unrelated to Java. The path is taken relative to the "current working directory" of your application. What that means exactly and how it is determined depends on a) your operating system and b) how you started your Java application